# How can I display a relative path instead of a full path in the title?

Tags: statusline, filenames

Out of the box title:

```
filename.txt (~/projects/blabla/foo/bar) - VIM
```

Desired title when the current folder `~/projects/blabla/foo`:

```
foo/bar/filename.txt 45/500
```

The last numbers represent current line / all lines. I got this with `%L-%P`.

Where can I read about title syntax? Is this the same as for `statusline`?

It looks like I can build a statusline in the title, which is potentially useful! I can display many things in the title, but minimalism is better for my computer's performance.

Comment: `:help 'titlestring'`

Comment: Moving the computation from the core to the runtime will certainly help you get a tailored title but it will be less performant. Minimalism is not only about looks.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using functions for the `titlestring`

I left some comments in there for you to take a look at and experiment with.

This is essentially how my titlestring is built in my `.vimrc`.

```
vim9script
def MyTitle(): string
  var user = $USER
  var hostname = hostname()
  var userhost = $"{user}@{hostname}"

  var fname = '%t'
  var fpath_relative = "(%f)"
  # var fpath_absolute = '(%F)'
  # var flag_modified = "%M"
  # var argument_list_status = "%a"
  var flags = '%h%w%m%r' # [help],[Preview],[+] (modified),[RO] (readonly)
  var cwd = substitute(getcwd(), $HOME, '~', '')
  var title_parts = [
        \ has('gui_running') ? "gvim " : "vim ",
        \ fname,
        \ flags,
        \ fpath_relative,
        \ $"[{cwd}]",
        \ $"({userhost})",
        \]

  return join(title_parts, '')
enddef

augroup vimrc
  autocmd!
  autocmd BufEnter * &titlestring = MyTitle()
augroup END
```

legacy

```
function s:MyTitle()
  let s:user = $USER
  let s:hostname = hostname()
  let s:userhost = $"{s:user}@{s:hostname}"

  let s:fname = '%t'
  let s:fpath_relative = "(%f)"
  " let s:fpath_absolute = '(%F)'
  " let s:flag_modified = "%M"
  " let s:argument_list_status = "%a"
  let s:flags = '%h%w%m%r' " [help],[Preview],[+] (modified),[RO] (readonly)
  let s:cwd = substitute(getcwd(), $HOME, '~', '')
  let s:title_parts = [
        \ has('gui_running') ? "gvim " : "vim ",
        \ s:fname,
        \ s:flags,
        \ s:fpath_relative,
        \ $"[{s:cwd}]",
        \ $"({s:userhost})",
        \]

  return join(s:title_parts, '')
endfunction

augroup vimrc
  autocmd!
  autocmd BufEnter * let &titlestring = s:MyTitle()
augroup END
```